# Como crear una fila que calcule el tiempo en dias, meses y años en Access?

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, ms-access, macros

Tengo una base de datos donde debo calcular el tiempo transcurrido de una fecha  a la actual.
Tengo entendido que con Excel las fórmulas con SIFECHA son:

```
=SIFECHA(B2+B3+B4,C2+C3+C4,"y")
=SIFECHA(B2+B3+B4,C2+C3+C4,"ym")
=SIFECHA(B2+B3+B4,C2+C3+C4,"md")
```

Pero no se en el caso de Access

Gracias

Comment: Hola!! probaste con alguna de las funciones de fecha de access???

Comment: Hola. Tú lo quieres para Access. ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? Otra cosa. Vendría bien si pusieras de qué datos partes y a dónde te gustaría llegar. Ejemplos.¡Gracias!

Comment: @gbianchi Si. En las funciones de columna calculado, pero genera error

Comment: Que fue lo que probaste?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes . Hasta ahora he creado una macro para este fin, pero no resuelve del todo el problema, por que no calcula todo

Comment: Por favor, tal y como dice @gbianchi,vendría bien que postees lo que ya has intentado en Access. Asimismo, unos datos de ejemplo también vendría bien. Necesitamos datos para poder intentar ayudarte de la mejor manera.

Comment: Una macro no es la solucion. Un query es tu solucion, que genere las 3 columnas como queres. Con funciones de access. Buscate las funciones de access?

Comment: Compañeros, ya encontre un ejemplo que me pudo ayudar a entender sobre este tema de funciones . Lo que no tengo claro es guardar esos registros por que solamente los muestra y calcula.

Answer (score 0):

El parametro utilizado es

```
Private Sub Comando8_Click()
    CalculaTiempoTranscurrido CDate(Me.txtFechaI & " " & Me.txtHoraI), CDate(Me.txtFechaF & " " & Me.txtHoraF)

    MsgBox "Años: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Años & Chr(13) & "Meses: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Meses & _
            Chr(13) & "Dias: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Dias & Chr(13) & _
            "Horas: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Horas & Chr(13) & "Minutos: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Minutos & _
            Chr(13) & "Segundos: " & TiempoTranscurrido.Segundos, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "TIEMPO TRANSCURRIDO"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.txtFechaF = Date
    Me.txtFechaI = Date - 42
    Me.txtHoraF = #5:30:00 PM#
    Me.txtHoraI = #8:00:00 AM#
End Sub
```

Pero solamente los muestra no agrega a tabla

Comment: esto es una respuesta a tu pregunta o información a dicional a tu pregunta original?

Comment: Es en parte respuesta, por solucionar algo en el proceso; pero se adiciona a la pregunta por solicitud de algunos usuarios